# general solution sum of two uniform random variables aY+bX=Z?

Tags: density-function, convolution

is there a general solution to that? I have seen simple examples for Y+X=Z but I was wondering how this would be with rescaling?

Comment: What do you mean by "general solution"?

Comment: Continuous or discrete uniform? Dependent or independent?

Answer (score 13):

If we have a variable $X\sim U(0,1)$ and multiply it by $a$, then $aX\sim U(0,a)$.

Assume that we're dealing with independent continuous uniform on $(0,a)$ and $(0,b)$ respectively (with $a<b$)

(This assumption is not restrictive since we can obtain the general case from this easily.)

Then the joint density is $\frac{1}{ab} I_{(0,a)}\times I_{(0,b)}$.

Since the bivariate density is constant where it's non-zero, we can just draw it "looking from above" by marking the boundary of that non-zero region.

[image: Bivariate uniform and corresponding convolution]

... and so by elementary geometric argument (along the lines of *(i) recognize that density increases linearly as the sum, $z$ goes from $0$ to $a$, stays constant until $b$ and then decreases linearly to $a+b$, and (ii) that the height in the middle section must be $1/b$ to get unit area, then (iii) the equations of the three non-zero sections follow immediately by inspection*), the density of the convolution is

$f(z) = \begin{cases} 0 & z\leq 0\\
z/ab & 0<z<a \\
1/b & a\leq z<b \\
(a+b-z)/ab & b\leq z<a+b \\
0 & z\geq a+b
\end{cases}$

[While formal integration will obviously work, it's somewhat quicker - for me at least - to proceed by something like the above reasoning, where one simply draws the density and then writes the result down immediately.]

---

The general case:

Imagine instead we had independent $U(c,a+c)$ and $U(d,d+b)$. Then the above density would simply be shifted right by $c+d$.

Comment: Great complement to [this other post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/195505/67822). The intuition is also clear, as you see the triangle expand from $U(0,1)$. I wish you did elaborate a bit more on the "elementary" geometric argument, though...

Comment: @Antoni that argument goes along the lines of 1. recognize that density increases linearly as z goes from 0 to a, stays constant until b and then decreases linearly to a+b. 2. that the height in the middle section must be 1/b to get unit area (though you can see it other ways as well). 3. the equations of the three non-zero sections follow immediately by inspection. Do you think that would help? (I worried it might be too obvious.)

Comment: It's perfect. Actually I did become clear after I went through the exercise of  putting together the more basic standard uniform videoclip on the post you commented on before (thank you). The color stripes are great. This is a very intuitive topic with some heavy lifting in the background. There is a good youtube on the topic [here](https://youtu.be/d_9KT2abCAY) if someone is interested.

Answer (score 6):

Define $Y'=aY$ and $X'=bX$, find their distribution, and you are back to the problem you know how to solve: $Y'+X'=Z$ (convolution).

Comment: Yes, but the convolution result is not the same as the one obtained for the convolution of iid $U(0,1)$ or $U(0,\alpha)$ random variables and requires more work to determine.